# Changing Training Period in Arima Model in R

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

Arima forecasts in R seem to change depending on the amount of data I input to the Arima() function. For example, I have a 30 days worth of sales data. If I input days 1-20 and forecast day 21, I get a different forecast than if I input days 10-20. This doesn't make sense to me because an Arima(p,d,q) model only looks at the previous p,q days data. So why would a forecast change if I change the amount of data I input into the function?

Comment: It is happening because of the error terms. That’s why it is called a model instead of a strict function like f(x)=y. Every different data brings unexpected info (aka  error term, stochastic part etc). It is the nature of the modeling. That is why cross validation is used  in cross section data sets.

Answer (score 0):

If you put more data into the arima function, it's gona use al data to train the model. This means that the predictor factors will also change. the function will try to find the coefficients that best predict fit the model. If you put more data, this coefficients will change too.

Comment: Thank you. Is more data always preferable? As an aside to this question, is it usual that my Arima model seems to be overfitting the data even after choosing the model based on nested cross validation? In other words, how do I make sure I'm not overfitting?